# Texture coordinate isn't working as desired when shading distributed plane with icospheres using geometry nodes

Tags: uv, shaders, geometry-nodes, texture-coordinates, shader-nodes

I'm trying to create an animation using a plane distributed with icospheres that is affected by another shape using the proximity attribute in geometry nodes.

Now the problem is when I use a texture coordinate with the object set to the icosphere it will see the entire plane distributed with icospheres as 1 object instead of separate objects.

So when I put a magic or wave texture on my icosphere using the UV texture coordinate, the icospheres distributed on my plane are a plain color instead of the desired effect of the texture. Or when I use a gradient texture using the generated or object coordinate the effect will be spread all over the plane instead of spread over the separate objects.

So how can I control the shaders of my distributed objects using geometry nodes as separate objects instead of 1 object?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For some reason, the instance UV is wiped, if the Geonodes modifier is not at the bottom of the stack? If you delete your _Simple Deform_ , it works. I don't know why, so not an answer.

Comment: @RobinBetts I can put the simple deform above the geometry modifier stack, seems to work I can still do animations with it. Thanks for pointing this out! Your comment counts as an answer for me!